Is it ethical to request partial reimbursement to present something from my previous position?
I'm a postdoc based in Western Europe, and I'll be going to a far foreign country in South Asia for two weeks to present something related to my previous postdoc. The conference is paying for my flight tickets and accommodation, which form the brunt of expenses. However, transport to the local airport (back and forth, in respective countries) and expenses like local transport and food won't be reimbursed by the conference. My previous postdoc manager is in the organizing committee, and he informed me that the rest of the cost would be born by me.
I've already informed my current postdoc manager long ago and he allowed me to attend the conference.
Given the above, I was wondering whether it's at all ethical to request my current postdoc manager for reimbursement for the expenses that won't be born by the conference? I do understand that the answer can be a resounding no, but I'm still checking in to see. Will it at least hurt to ask, or will it be unethical in the first place?

The fact that your airfare and accommodation is covered is a huge help. Your per diem will add up, though over two weeks. Have you asked your previous institution? || I wouldn't phrase it as a "request for reimbursement," but rather "are you able to partially fund my conference?"

Personal experience: in a somewhat similar situation, there was a kind of negotiation between my previous and current PI. They agreed to share the cost, but with the condition that my affiliation would be something like: Prev affiliation X, now working in affiliation Y (as footnote).

@AzorAhai-him- Thank you, there doesn't seem to be a per diem :( I'll rephrase the question accordingly and discuss what I can give back; possibly a mention  of this work under the funding from the current place as well, but only after checking with my ex manager.

Usually conference expenses are paid by some form of grant. Usually, grants have expectations about how travel funds are used, the exact language is going to vary but there will ordinarily be some sort of requirement that the goals of the grant are served by the travel.
Some PIs may be willing to push the boundaries of that requirement more than others, but I'd recommend thinking ahead of time about what purpose this travel serves towards however you are currently funded. You're presenting work from a previous postdoc, but if you can attend sessions related to your current work I think it's an easier sell.
All that aside, I think it's perfectly reasonable to ask, far more reasonable than it is for your old supervisor to be okay with making you pay your own way. Echoing Jon Custer's comment, the boundaries between academic jobs are often a bit fuzzy, unlike an industry job where the expectation is that as soon as you move on to a new job you completely stop working for your employer unless they're paying you to continue to consult. In academia, it's appreciated that different stops and funding sources along the way are in some sense funding you as a person, and as a result it's normal to be working on "old" stuff when you move to a new position: conference presentations, paper submissions and revisions, support for people taking over your old role. If your current supervisor is willing to fund travel for your past work, you should also be willing to contribute to work with that supervisor (in a limited scope) when you move on to your next position: presenting work, moving work you've done through the publication process, etc.

I will echo some of the other answers.
I think it is perfectly fine to ask. The only limitation may be by the "color" of the money your PI would have to use. Some grants have strict restrictions (and regular audits) on what is a reasonable justification for sending you to a conference, if what you are presenting is unrelated to currently funded work.
From my perspective, I keep several lines of unrestricted funds which I use for situations like this, which I justify as "professional development". Your PI may or may not have such funds. They may however have funding that is otherwise liberal in supporting your development. In addition to that, it never hurts to ask your Department chair if there are any small pots of money to support partial conference travel. After all, if you are presenting, presumably attending poster sessions and interacting with various academics and students, you are representing your current department, and may even be doing "recruiting".

In general, an ask that doesn't involve deception isn't unethical. So, yes, it is ok to ask, while giving complete information.
However, turning you down is warranted as you probably get some benefit from the presentation that is worth as much or more than your costs. The current PI and their projects may not benefit much.
A partial reimbursement might be helpful, but the accounting for expenses that the PI needs to make might make even this impossible. But a discussion and an ask isn't unethical.

I always supported my (new) postdocs going to conferences to present previous work. It kept them out in the field, and I knew that in 6 months or so they would have our work to present instead, and likely they would present that for 3-6 months after they moved to their next job. All part of trying to make sure they had a good position to move to.

@JonCuster, certainly an enlightened position. Good if it is widespread.

"turning you down is warranted as you probably get some benefit from the presentation" I think I know what you're getting at, but this is a little confusingly phrased.

I, on the other hand, have no idea whatsoever what that sentence is meant to mean. It benefits you academically so they should turn you down? What?

@N.Virgo, If all of the benefits of the attendance accrue to the individual and none to the institution then that institution is justified in not funding. That is, perhaps a big "if", but that is the meaning. And I didn't say that the "should" turn you down.

I guess there might be some institutions that don't see a benefit to their members as a benefit to themselves, but I hope I never have to work at one
